# Viewport3D performance on a simple mesh

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewport3d

I created a full-screen WPF `Canvas`, representing a time line. Only the visible part of the time line is composed, so (practically) no UI elements lie outside of the visible range.

[image: Time line 2D]

I'm trying to add perspective to this time line using a `Viewport3D`. The result at the moment looks as follows:

[image: Time line 3D]

You can scroll the time line left and right by dragging. Performance in the 2D version is great. However, once the canvas is placed inside a `Viewport3D` using `Viewport2DVisual3D`, performance drops drastically.

It's not like I'm rendering a complex mesh, **where is this performance decrease coming from, and can I prevent it?**

To give you an idea of how the 3D perspective was realized I'll add the XAML code here, unfortunately it doesn't work on its own.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
    <Viewport3D ClipToBounds="False">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera
                Position="0 0 5"
                LookDirection="0.4 0 -1"
                UpDirection="0 1 0" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <ContainerUIElement3D>
            <ModelUIElement3D>
                <AmbientLight Color="White" />
            </ModelUIElement3D>
        </ContainerUIElement3D>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D
                    TriangleIndices="0,1,2 2,3,0"
                    TextureCoordinates="0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0">
                    <MeshGeometry3D.Positions>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AspectRatioToPositions}">
                            <Binding ElementName="TimeLineContainer" Path="Width" />
                            <Binding ElementName="TimeLineContainer" Path="Height" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </MeshGeometry3D.Positions>
                </MeshGeometry3D>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial
                    Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"
                    Brush="White" />
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

            <Grid 
                x:Name="TimeLineContainer"
                Width="1650" Height="600"
                ClipToBounds="True"
                Background="{StaticResource TimeLineBrush}"
                Behaviors:MouseBehavior.LeftClickDragCommand="ActivityOverview:ActivityOverviewWindow.MouseDragged"
                MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel"
                MouseMove="OnMouseMoved">

                <ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl x:Name="TimeLine" Focusable="True">
                    <ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl.CommandBindings>
                        <CommandBinding
                            Command="ActivityOverview:ActivityOverviewWindow.MouseDragged"                  
                            Executed="MoveTimeLine" />
                    </ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl.CommandBindings>
                </ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl>

            </Grid>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Comment: There could be all sorts of reasons, if you don't have hardware acceleration on your graphics card being one.

Comment: @ChrisF: I have hardware acceleration, and the mesh is just two triangles.

Comment: Can you post the minimum code that repeats the problem. Also when I was doing 3D (many years ago now) there were issues on some cards if you were using gradient fills - which I notice you are. Try removing that. If nothing else it will eliminate it as a possibility.

Comment: @ChrisF: Removing the gradients didn't make a difference. They worked fluently in the 2D version as well. I'm thinking of hit tests which might be more expensive in 3D now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Viewport2DVisual3D` performance can be slow when you attempt to display content that is time-consuming to render. This seemed to be the case in my example.

For this reason, you can set the [`CacheMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d.cachemode.aspx) of `Viewport2DVisual3D`.

```
<Viewport2DVisual3D>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache />
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.CacheMode>        
    ...
</Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

Starting from Windows Vista, anti-aliasing is enabled by default. Disabling this also helps in improving performance. It's weird this would have a big impact with such a simple mesh (two triangles), but on my PC, it does!

```
<Viewport3D ClipToBounds="False" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
```

Combining these two settings, I got great improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys you can use `<OrthographicCamera Position="0 0 5" LookDirection="0.4 0 -1"   UpDirection="0 1 0" />` . Please check my code below

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
<Viewport3D ClipToBounds="False">
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <OrthographicCamera
            Position="0 0 5"
            LookDirection="0.4 0 -1"
            UpDirection="0 1 0" />
    </Viewport3D.Camera>

    <ContainerUIElement3D>
        <ModelUIElement3D>
            <AmbientLight Color="White" />
        </ModelUIElement3D>
    </ContainerUIElement3D>

    <Viewport2DVisual3D>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <MeshGeometry3D
                TriangleIndices="0,1,2 2,3,0"
                TextureCoordinates="0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0">
                <MeshGeometry3D.Positions>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AspectRatioToPositions}">
                        <Binding ElementName="TimeLineContainer" Path="Width" />
                        <Binding ElementName="TimeLineContainer" Path="Height" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </MeshGeometry3D.Positions>
            </MeshGeometry3D>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial
                Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"
                Brush="White" />
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

        <Grid 
            x:Name="TimeLineContainer"
            Width="1650" Height="600"
            ClipToBounds="True"
            Background="{StaticResource TimeLineBrush}"
            Behaviors:MouseBehavior.LeftClickDragCommand="ActivityOverview:ActivityOverviewWindow.MouseDragged"
            MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel"
            MouseMove="OnMouseMoved">

            <ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl x:Name="TimeLine" Focusable="True">
                <ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl.CommandBindings>
                    <CommandBinding
                        Command="ActivityOverview:ActivityOverviewWindow.MouseDragged"                  
                        Executed="MoveTimeLine" />
                </ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl.CommandBindings>
            </ActivityOverview:TimeLineControl>

        </Grid>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

Comment: Why would I need/want to use a different camera?